# Combining Apache 2.0 with closed source

Tags: derivative-works, apache-2.0

I want to use a third party software C-library "**A**" commerially in a product "**P**" (in fact a firmware, running on a device).

The third party product "**A**" is subject to **Apache 2 license**.
That means, I have to give a notice to the user of the final product "**P**" about using this open source library.

Now I have a third library "**C**" from a company (in fact it is a driver for a part of a microcontroller. We are allowed to use "**C**" internally for developing "**P**". We are not allowed to give away "**C**" to anybody else, beside of the object code generated.

Question:

Is it allowed to make adaptations of "**A**" in a way to call functions of "**C**" within "**A**" ?

We do not need to make our changes of "**A**" public, but can there be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are allowed to do what you describe. There are no restrictions against commercial use and the Apache 2.0 license is not reciprocal like, for instance, the GPL version 2.0. It's totally possible and not at all uncommon to combine Apache 2.0 licensed software with proprietary software. The proprietary software will stay proprietary.